# Python Pandas - Cleaning data column depending on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I have the following code to create a column with cleaned up zip codes for the USA and Canada

```
df = pd.read_csv(file1)
usa = df['Region'] == 'USA'
canada = df['Region'] == 'Canada'
df.loc[usa, 'ZipCleaned'] = df.loc[usa, 'Zip'].str.slice(stop=5)
df.loc[canada, 'ZipCleaned'] = df.loc[canada, 'Zip'].str.replace(' |-','')
```

The problem is that some of the rows that have "USA" as the country contain Canadian postal codes in the dataset. So the USA logic from above is being applied to Canadian postal codes.

I tried the edited code below along with teh above and experimented with one provinces ("BC") to prevent the USA logic from being applied in this case but it didn't work

```
usa = df['Region'] == 'USA' and df['Ship To State'] != 'BC'
```

Comment: I would prefer to create a list containing all provinces so that the USA logic does not get applied if the Country is USA but a province is Canadian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves this question

```
df.loc[~df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]'), 'ZipCleaned'] = df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.slice(stop=5)
df.loc[df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]'), 'ZipCleaned'] = df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.replace(' |-','')
```